# Database Stored Procedure moving issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to move all the stored procedures from an old database to a new database through SQL queries.

I have created the `Database` through a `Dynamic stored procedure` & it has worked fine. I have moved all the `tables` as well but I am not able to move the `stored procedures` to the new database.

I tried pasting `SQL statements` into a table but i don't know to execute them.

> Is there an easy way to migrate my stored procedures?

I got all the stored procedures which are created in old database by the following query

```
Select Name from '+@OldDatabse+'.sys.procedures
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Link your old database server in your page

```
$old_host= "OLD DB IP";
$old_db = "OLD DB"

$new_host ="localhost";
$new_db= "new_db";

$old_con=mysql_connect($old_host,$old_db);

mysql_select_db($old_db,$old_con);
mysql_select_db($new_db,$new_con);
```

Comment: :Thank you for response, i want in queries to generate Sp from old database to new database

Answer (score 0):

You have do with this way

> try this following

- Right click on database >
- Tasks >
- Generate Scripts >
- Select the objects you wish to script( Store-Procedure  or table  ) >
- Script to File ( Where you got the script code  details) >
- Set schema or data or schema with data for Table (if you take a sp , then don't set anything)
- Run generated scripts against target database .

If you need to move this by using query, then look at this link :

[Copy all SP's from one Database to another Database using a script](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/646dedb7-3507-4e21-9d24-834bc43e023f/copy-all-sps-from-one-database-to-another-database-using-a-script)

---

**Update:**

...........

Here is a 4 option for move the Stored-procedure '

**Option 1:** Use the scripting wizard Right-click the db --> tasks --> Generate scripts --> go through the wizard.

---

**Option 2:** Open the stored procedures folder in SSMS (in the object explorer details window). (You can also press F7 to do so, see [this blog](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/scripting-all-jobs-on-sql-server-2005-20) for details). You can use shift+click to select all the stored procedures and you can then right-click and script them to a file.

---

**Options 3**: The simplest of them.

```
bcp "SELECT definition + char(13) + 'GO' FROM MyDatabase.sys.sql_modules s INNER JOIN MyDatabase.sys.procedures p ON [s].[object_id] = [p].[object_id] WHERE p.name LIKE 'Something%'" queryout "c:\SP_scripts.sql" -S MyInstance -T -t -w
```

---

**Option 4 :** To script All the Stored Procedures in the Database

```
SELECT    O.Name as ProcName 
        ,M.Definition as CreateScript 
        ,O.Create_Date 
        ,O.Modify_Date 
FROM sys.sql_modules as M INNER JOIN sys.objects as O 
ON M.object_id = O.object_id 
WHERE O.type = 'P'
```

> If the Stored Procedure is created with ENCRYPTION option then you will get the NULL in the definition column.

Comment: Thank you for response, I want in Sql queries

Comment: See me answer , and look the link !

Comment: i didnt get the answer in that blog

Comment: :i tried your method but how to execute the content of an sp in new database, I am not clear about that can you please explain me on that...?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicates of below link:

[SQL Server - copy stored procedures from one db to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703424/sql-server-copy-stored-procedures-from-one-db-to-another)

- Right click on database
- Tasks
- Generate Scripts
- Select the objects you wish to script
- Script to File
- Run generated scripts against target database

I hope it will help you.. :)